# How can I solve this problem? Android studio update error.. jre/bin/java.exe is absent

Tags: java, android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OGKT.png)

I want to update the latest version in android studio, but I have this problem lol...
So, I try to copy java.exe(in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\bin) to C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jre\bin, But, the update isn't still working...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2o2y.png)
how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just copy one executable **java.exe** and expect everything to work as normal.
There are other files on which **java.exe** depends, finding and copying them one by one will be tough.

So, i'll suggest you to re-download *jdk package* and do a install.

Comment: you can, follow these [instructions](https://java.com/en/download/help/download_options.xml) for java installation